# Does there exist a sequence uniformly bounded in $L^{\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ but not $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Suppose there exists a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_{n}\}$ and a constant $C>0$ independent of $n$ with $$\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})} \le C,$$i.e. for every compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}(K)} \le C$. Does this imply that $$\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})} \le C? $$

**attempt:** I think the answer is yes.  Suppose for a contradiction that for some $n =N$ we have $\|f_{N}\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})} > C$. Then since $f_{N}$ is continuous there exists an open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $f_{N}(x) > C$ for $x \in A$.  But since $f_{N}$ is in $L^{\infty}_{loc}$ we can say that $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}(\bar{A})} \le C$ where $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$. This contradicts our assumption and so the statement is false.

Have i made a mistake?

Comment: What's the difference between $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R})}$ and $\|f\|_{L^\infty_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R})}$?

Comment: One point sets $\{x\}$ are compact. Therefore your assumptions imply $|f_n(x)|\le C$ for every $x$ and $n.$ Hence $\|f_n\|_{L^\infty}\le C.$

Comment: To add to @UmbertoP., usually we don't put norms on the locally integrable spaces. The whole point of these spaces is that the full norm is infinite, but the blowup is at the boundary, or at infinity, so we can make sense of norms on compact sets (but there is little point in trying to put a local norm on the full domain).

Comment: OK i see where i am making a mistake, the definition i was using for the loc space made it equivalent to the regular space. In fact for the purpose of my problem the C should depend on the compact set K. but then the implication definitely isn't true because you can have something like the identity function. thanks for pointing it out